# command line tool for getting machine readable wifi scan list

Tags: linux, wifi

I am looking for a cli tool for machine readable wifi scanner.
I tried `iwlist` which does not look like machine readable, e.g. bitrates are oddly reported

```
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
```

and another tool `iw` which seems quite useful but help says:

> Do NOT screenscrape this tool, we don't consider its output stable.

I haven't tried `nmcli` because on my distro seems not available.

### Edit

Currently I need only small subset of properties, SSID, BSSID, but I expect that in the future I will need more information, e.g. if network is encrypted, encryption mode (WPA,WPA2,WPA3...), if it uses shared key or not and more. So I am asking for tool, which does not have to provide a lot information but with some guarantee of output stability.

Primary I need it for Raspbian distribution.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and specify exactly what output you want from this tool. Are you trying to get bitrates? Available network names? Something else? Also, what operating system are you using? Does this need to work on _any_ *nix? On UNIX only? On Linux only? Something else?

Comment: The output of `iw wlan0 scan` can be easily postprocessed, e.g. with `grep` or `awk`. If you want something that spits out, say, JSON, you probably need to take the source of `iw` and modify it.